# CMD for unable to move files due to string butchering

Tags: string, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I'm trying to format my USB stick for use in my car as music database. 
However, my radio can only playback one folder at a time, so I thought it would be helpful to move all titles of an artist to the artist's folder.

Since this are like 32GB of music that would be a lot of work by hand.

I've come up with the following script to do the job (G:\ being the USB drive)

```
FOR /F %%T IN ('dir G:\ /B /A:D') DO (
    FOR /R %%D IN (G:\%%T\*.*) DO MOVE "%%d" "G:\%%T"
)
```

So far this works, but the  `'dir G:\ /B /A:D'` command ends up butchering the folder names in this fashion: "FOLDER NAME" -> "FOLDER". So it essentially just picks up the first word for some reason.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FOR` metavariable is one of the few places in batch that is case-sensitive. The `%%D` mst match the `%%d` - or vice-versa.

(but you'd probably do well to include `"delims="` between the `FOR/f` and the metavariable...) to ensure that the entire string is assigned to the metavariable.

Answer (score 0):

Change your outer FOR command:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%T in ('dir /b /a:d "G:\"') DO (
 ...
)
```