# CMD "MOVE /Y" asks for confirmation

Tags: batch-file, cmd, move, prompt

I'm still working on getting this: [CMD for unable to move files due to string butchering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20773056/cmd-for-unable-to-move-files-due-to-string-butchering/20773099?noredirect=1#20773099) to work.

My batch script looks like this right now,

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%T IN ('dir G:\ /B /A:D') DO (
  CD "G:\%%T"
  FOR /R %%D IN (*) DO (MOVE /Y "%%D" "G:\%%T")
)
PAUSE
```

and does as I intended, however as soon as it finds a duplicate file, it asks what it's supposed to do (overwrite: yes/no/all) for EACH file. Ordering to replace ALL only replaces one file.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Op1Ao.jpg

Why does it do that, and how do I fix it?

EDIT:
Turns out to be a windows bug of sorts. `ROBOCOPY` or `XCOPY` both work and their quiet switches work.

Answer (score 2):

As you said, Robocopy does what you need and it smart about doing it.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1073.robocopy-and-a-few-examples.aspx

Comment: The one down side to robocopy is that it [exits non-zero](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/954404) on success in some situations. According to MS documentation, any exit code above eight indicates an error, so if you want to do any error checking, you have to use something like `IF ERRORLEVEL 9 ...`

Comment: Good point. ERRORLEVEL non-zero seems to have changed over time to mean _maybe_ an error occurred. Seems like they should've left a buffer of codes after 8 in case something else occurs so you don't have to change hardcodes from >= 9.

Answer (score 2):

since windows 2000, the behaviour of the command is to prompt for confirmation regardless of the `/y` switch, unless the command is triggered from a script.

you can override this by setting the environment variable `COPYCMD` to `/Y` before running your move command. eg: `SET COPYCMD=/Y && move /Y a b`

this behaviour is documented at: https://ss64.com/nt/move.html

Answer (score 0):

Funny bc.

/y   : Suppresses prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an existing destination file.

/-y   : Causes prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an existing destination file.

Have u tried a little /y ?

Comment: Nope, a lower case Y doesn't do the trick either. I ended up using robocopy /Y [target] [dest], which worked

Answer (score 0):

Strange thing...

`move /?` says (translated, because my help is german):

you have to confirm overwriting by default, **in spite you call it from a batch file**.

I just tried this very simple batchfile:

```
move test.txt test
```

test.txt is moved into folder test and the existing file is overwritten without confirmation.
When I give this command at the prompt (not batchfile), it asks for overwriting (as designed)

So all you have to do is removing `/Y` (strange, but fact)

(using Win7 - if this matters)